# What's the best way to push new table rows to a browser?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, push-notification, real-time

I've got a MySQL database and every few minutes and hours new rows get inserted representing new news items. How can open browsers receive these new news items to be placed at the top of an HTML table?

At the top of the HTML table it could display "x new items" (x changes periodically as new items get inserted) and when clicked the new items are placed at the top of the table as new rows. This is just like most other real-time web apps: twitter search, disqus comments, YT comments, hckrnews.

I'm running a LAMP setup and happy to use HTML5, Jquery but would like to keep things simple, easy and ubiquitous. I don't mind polling the server for updates, and  ideally would like to give users the option to turn the polling(or push) on or off.

Comment: yes, I suppose an ajax method could poll for new rows, display a number as a link, then if pressed get those rows and insert at top of table, then reset the new rows count. I'll have to find some code examples. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls every X seconds or minutes. Then with jQuery you can insert the new data to the existing table.

Pseudo code:

- Set a JavaScript timer with interval X sec/min.
- After each interval send a request to the server with Ajax. You may need a parameter like last id, last datetime or something similar to tell the server which records are displayed already.
- Get the response and insert dynamically the new rows at the top of the table and write "X new items" using `responseData.length` somewhere.

More complicated alternative to Ajax is to implement Comet but it's a little bit difficult with PHP and Apache as I heard (didn't try).

---

**Untested example:**

```
setInterval(function() {
    var currentRowsCount = $('#tableId tr').length - 1; // or ID or Date
    var table = $('#tableId');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: { rows: currentRowsCount },
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function( response ) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(response);

        $(data).each(function(key, value) {
            // add the new rows using any of the append, prepend, before or after methods
        })
    });
}, 60000); // 1 min
```

Comment: that's a great answer, I wonder if there's some code already written that does all that. thx.

Comment: I added an example. We don't know nothing concrete for your table and your data from the database, so maybe it would be better to ask a new question when this part is done.

Comment: ok. thx. It'd be better to get an attribute from the top row of the table representing the id or time of that row and send back to server on polling to get anything newer. Is (var table) actually used above? (Also, I've had problems in past getting info from table after it's already been adjusted by jquery after initial rendering.) I think the info needs to come from DOM.

Comment: `table` variable is not used but you will need it to prepend/append the new rows. About the problems with getting info I can't say anything. If that occurs again you can try to dynamically create your new `td` and `tr` elements instead of creating just strings like `<tr><td>...`.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this in jquery this is for message alerting but can be modified to update your table rows easy enough use it as a concept to develop on not copy line for line.

```
<script>
        var messages = {
        endpoint: 'endpoint.php',
        interval: 5, // polling interval, seconds

        poll: function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: messages.endpoint,
                data: {
                    'method': 'messages-poll'
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $(data).each(function(){
                        //Your table update functionality here
                    });

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        messages.poll();
                    }, messages.interval * 1000);
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        }
    };

    messages.poll();
</script>
```

Comment: ok, thx, so there needs to be some other function that executes poll every so often, typically with last-id or last-time parameter for looking up the database on endpoint.php? I suppose the issue here, is once new rows are added to the table, the next poll needs to get last-id or last-time from those new rows, (they won't be in the actual original html)

Comment: You'll have to add in your own tracking of the last returned ID which is easy enough to do and pass it into messages.poll(). so it knows where to poll from but if you return json array from your endpoint.php its easy enough to do.  You don't need another function to execute the poll every so often this block of code automatically does that if you lok at the bottom there's messages.poll outside of the var messages and then inside the var messages on success theres a setTimeout out so it self calls in other words when the script runs the first time it calls self and then runs on loop after that